# Custom error pages

Tags: c#, error-handling

I have configured the HttpErrors section in my web.config.

My custom error page is shown, but not when an exception occurs outside a web request (eg: Application startup, module initializing...), I get the following error:
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

How can I make sure that my custom error page is ALWAYS shown?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The customer error pages are being configured at the start of the ASP.NET application, which fails in your case. There is no ASP.NET pipeline to handle the error pages.

Usually there is not much to do, besides making a proxy that filters out HTTP 500 error messages and replaces it with another message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain me how to configure a proxy to filter out the 500 error messages?

Comment: That would require quite some time. You could check out Apache or Nginx.

Comment: What type of setup is this? Are you using MVC or WebForms? IIS?